# Determining the number of occurrences of each unique element in a vector

Tags: matlab

How can I determine the relative frequency of a value in a MATLAB vector?

```
vector = [ 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 ];
```

What function will return the number of occurrences of each unique element?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `unique` in combination with `histc` to get the relative frequency.

```
A=[1,2,3,1,2,4,2,1]; %#an example vector
unqA=unique(A);
```

This gives the unique elements as `unqA=[1,2,3,4]`. To get the number of occurances,

```
countElA=histc(A,unqA); %# get the count of elements
relFreq=countElA/numel(A);
```

This gives `countElA=[3,3,1,1]` and `relFreq=[0.3750, 0.3750, 0.1250, 0.1250]`, which is the relative frequency of the unique elements. This will work for both integers and floating points.

Answer (score 10):

For the most general case where you have a vector of floating point values, you can use the functions [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) and [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[uniqueValues,~,uniqueIndex] = unique(vector);
frequency = accumarray(uniqueIndex(:),1)./numel(vector);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function tabulate. See this example with your vector.

```
vector = [ 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 ];
tabulate(vector);
  Value    Count   Percent
      1        7     38.89%
      2       11     61.11%
```

If you need it in percent order, do:

```
t = tabulate(vector);
t = sortrows(t, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring from [this](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96504-how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-each-element-in-a-vector-in-matlab) answer:

```
unqV = unique(vector);
y = zeros(size(unqV));
for i = 1:length(unqV)
    y(i) = sum(unqV(i)==vector);
end
```

unqV = [1 2]
 y = [7 11]