# Count duplicate numbers in column

Tags: matlab

This is my data:

```
3  3  2
2  4  1
4  1  2
7  5  2
3  4  1
2  6  2
1  5  1
```

I want somehow to return me that there is 3 duplicates of 1 and 4 duplicates of 2.

I tried `find(ismember(e(:,3),set)` where `set = [1, 2]` and `length(strfind(e(:,3),'1'))` but they not worked... couldn't find anything else

It would be better if it return me it like that

```
ans = 
      3 1
      4 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unique` and `histc` to count occurrences of elements:

```
[U, ia, iu] = unique(A(:, 3));   %// Vector of unique values and their indices
counts = histc(iu, 1:numel(U));  %// Count values
res = [counts(:), U];
```

#### Example

Let's apply this to your example:

```
A = [3 3 2; 2 4 1; 4 1 2; 7 5 2; 3 4 2; 2 6 1; 1 5 1];
[U, ia, iu] = unique(A(:, 3));
counts = histc(iu, 1:numel(U));
res = [counts(:), U];
```

What we get is:

```
res =
     3     1
     4     2
```

Comment: Why we need ia? Its not doing anything
Edit: oh ok I get it

Answer (score 5):

the best in this case is to use `tabulate`.

```
m = tabulate(a(:,3))

m =

1.0000    3.0000   42.8571
2.0000    4.0000   57.1429

[m(:,1), m(:,2)]

ans =

 1     3
 2     4
```

Comment: +1: Nice, I didn't know about `tabulate`, but it _is_ worth noting that it requires the Statistics Toolbox installed... Also, instead of writing `[m(:, 1), m(:, 2)]` you can simply write `m(:, 1:2)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = [3  3  2
        2  4  1
        4  1  2
        7  5  2
        3  4  1
        2  6  2
        1  5  1];

d = data(:,3); %extract relevant data
u = unique(d)'; %find unique list of numbers
D = repmat(d, 1, length(u)); 
s = sum(bsxfun(@eq, u, D)); %count occurences of each number in the unique list
ans = [s', u']
```

**EDIT:**

Better answers found here: [Determining the number of occurrences of each unique element in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385651/determining-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-unique-element-in-a-vector)