# Given a table of data and number of occurrences, can I create the underlying dataset?

Tags: matlab, run-length-encoding

I have a 2-column matrix that describes a piece of data, and the number of times that data occurred within a set:

```
A = [1    6                              
     2    2
     3    8                                                                       
     4    1 
     5    3];
```

Given that, is there an "elegant" way to produce the underlying dataset? i.e.,

```
B = [1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 5];
```

There are plenty of ways to go from `B` to `A` ([`tabulate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html), using [`unique` and `histc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385651/determining-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-unique-element-in-a-vector), etc) but I couldn't find any way to go from `A` to `B`. The best I could do is not elegant:

```
B = [];
for ii = 1:size(A,1)
    B = [B repmat(A(ii,1), 1, A(ii,2))];
end
```

I have a sneaking suspicion the "correct" way to do this is to use `bsxfun` or `accumarray`, but I am not experienced enough to understand how these really work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Element-wise array replication according to a count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382319/element-wise-array-replication-according-to-a-count), [MATLAB Array Manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975772/matlab-array-manipulation)

Comment: @Dang Khoa You're looking for [_run-length decoding_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). See the duplicate Amro posted!

Comment: @EitanT thanks! I didn't realize this kind of scheme had a name. I voted to close, as this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'arrayfun' in combination with 'cell2mat':

```
 B = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) ones(y,1)*x, A(:,1), A(:,2), 'uniformoutput', false))'
```

This results in

```
B =

  Columns 1 through 16

     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3

  Columns 17 through 20

     4     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more option. I wouldn't call it elegant, but it's pretty efficient.

```
ndx = cumsum([1; A(:,2)]);
B = zeros(1, ndx(end)-1);
B(ndx(1:end-1)) = 1;
B = A(cumsum(B), 1).';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not super elegant either, but this may work:

```
B = {A(:,1)*ones(1,A(:,2)};
B = [B{:}];
```

Have no matlab to check syntax, idea is to remove loop from

```
B=[];
for ii=1:size(A,1)
   B=[B A(i,1)*ones(1,A(i,2)];
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `bsxfun`:

```
B = A(1+sum(bsxfun(@lt, cumsum(A(:,2)), 1:sum(A(:,2)))), 1).';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to H.Muster post

using `repmat`

```
B=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y)(repmat(x,y,1) ), A(:,1), A(:,2), ...
                                   'UniformOutput', false));
```

`B'` is expected output.