# Find the indices in a vector efficiently in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have this vector something like this

```
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
.
.
.
```

What I want to know is in how many rows the individual numbers appeared something like this

```
1 1
2 3
3 4
. .
. .
```

I can loop through each element and use

```
index = find(vector == element)
length(index)
```

But that is very inefficient. What is the most efficient way  to do it in matlab?

Comment: Does this previous question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385651/determining-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-unique-element-in-a-vector

Comment: IS the vector sorted?

Comment: @RobertP. No it is not

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

> bincounts = histc(x,binranges) counts the number of values in x that
>   are within each specified bin range.

If you combine `histc` with `unique`, you can get what you want:

```
a =
     4
     2
     3
     3
     1
     2
     1
     1
     2
     3

uni = unique(a);
[uni, histc(a,uni)]
ans =
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3
     4     1
```

Comment: Really nice answer! I might use this in the future!