# Find non-unique elements of an array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If I have an array `[1 2 3 4 3 5 6 7 8 7]`, I'd like to find the list of non-unique entries: `[3 7]`. I fail to find a simple way to do it. Any idea?

**Update:** I'd like to have a universal solution, which would also work with cell array of strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385651/determining-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-unique-element-in-a-vector

Comment: @gregswiss: I need a list of duplicated elements rather than how often they are encountered. Besides, the solutions in the linked question are not applicable to non-numeric arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If A has length n, you can find the indices in A of the first occurrence of each entry and remove them from A:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 3 5 6 7 8 7];
n=length(A);
[~,IA,~] = unique(A);
out = unique(A(setdiff((1:n),IA)))
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach with [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) -

```
[unqA,~,id] = unique(A);
out = unqA(histc(id,1:max(id))>1)
```

Or use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) in place of `histc` -

```
out = unqA(accumarray(id(:),1)>1)
```

Or use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
out = unqA(sum(bsxfun(@eq,id(:),1:max(id(:)).'))>1)
```

Sample runs -

1) Numeric arrays case -

```
>> A
A =
     6     3     7     7     4     3     8     5     2     3     1
>> [unqA,~,id] = unique(A);
>> unqA(histc(id,1:max(id))>1)
ans =
     3     7
>> unqA(accumarray(id(:),1)>1)
ans =
     3     7
>> unqA(sum(bsxfun(@eq,id(:),1:max(id(:)).'))>1)
ans =
     3     7
```

2) Cell arrays case -

```
>> A = {'apple','banana','apple','mango','ball','cat','banana','apple'};

>> [unqA,~,id] = unique(A);
>> unqA(histc(id,1:max(id))>1)
ans = 
    'apple'    'banana'
>> unqA(accumarray(id(:),1)>1)
ans = 
    'apple'    'banana'
>> unqA(sum(bsxfun(@eq,id(:),1:max(id(:)).'))>1)
ans = 
    'apple'    'banana'
```

Comment: Nowadays, `histcounts` is recommended instead of `histc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
x=[1 2 3 4 3 5 6 7 8 7];
y=x;
[~,ind,~]=unique(y);
y(ind)=[];
```

y is the non-unique entries.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for a more generic solution, here is one that should be easily adaptable to other data types. Compared to others it is also a O(n) solution - but the drawback is the slow Matlab looping on large array of elements...

```
A = [1 2 3 4 3 5 6 7 8 7];
dupes = [];

map = containers.Map('KeyType', class(A), 'ValueType' , 'logical');
for i=1:numel(A)
    if map.isKey(A(i))
        dupes = [dupes A(i)];
    else
        map(i) = true;
    end        
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach using `sort` and `diff`:

```
As = sort(A);
out = unique(As([false diff(As)==0]));
```

Comment: It seems more than two occurrences of a number would give duplicated entries in the output, unless I missed something.

Comment: @Divakar No, you don't miss anything, you're absolutely right. Thanks Steve to have edited my answer.